# empty() vs isEmpty() in Java Stack class

Tags: java

Why does `Stack` in Java have an `empty()` method along with the usual `isEmpty()`? All abstract classes that `Stack` extends have an `isEmpty()` method.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: What the return type of `empty()`?

Comment: Both have return type boolean

Comment: Basically the `isEmpty()` method was introduced with the `Collections ` class (JDK 1.2) which came after the `Stack` class (JDK 1.0)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I believe OP's question is more on : why there are duplicated methods, given `empty()` and `isEmpty()` are doing the same thing?

If you take a closer look, in `Vector`, `Stack` and `HashTable`, there are more examples of methods doing similar thing with different names.

Here is the brief history:

At the time of JDK 1.0, there was no "Collection" framework in Java.  `Stack`, `Vector`, `HashTable` were some of the basic data structures provided by Java.

Later in JDK 1.2, *Collection* framework was added to JDK, and standard interfaces (like `List`, `Map`) were introduced.

However in these new standard collection interfaces, methods were named in a different convention.  The change in naming convention was most probably influenced by Java Bean standard introduced also in JDK 1.2.  These method names were different from those in old `Stack`, `Vector` and `HashTable` classes.  For example, it was named `empty()` in original class but was named `isEmpty()` of `Collection` interface.

In order to make `Stack`, `Vector` and `HashTable` compatible with Collection framework, `Stack`, `Vector` and `HashTable` has implemented its corresponding Collection interfaces.  On the same time, old methods were kept for the sake of backward compatibility.

Hence the "duplicated" methods you see now.

Comment: sadly the `@depricated` annotation was also introduced later - and is still missing in `Stack`

Comment: @MartinFrank I don't think the reason for Stack not being deprecated is because of unavailability of `@Deprecated` .  Actually concept of deprecation was in Java much earlier than what you thought.  It was originally done in Javadoc.  There is simply no obvious reason to deprecate Stack.

Comment: Stack is totally worth it! but the duality of `empty()` and `isEmpty()` should be cleaned up - sorry, i was not clear about that...

Comment: @MartinFrank Well, Deque in Collections framework is better alternatives of Stack.  The reason Stack/Vector etc not deprecated, from my understanding, is because they are considered to be legacy APIs which is something will be kept to keep older code from running.  Although they are obsoleted, they are not (yet) considered to be deprecated, for which means being prohibited to use (and may be removed in future).  If they are considered to be legacy code, the old methods (empty()) shouldn't be marked deprecated else it will lose the purpose of keeping these legacy  classes

Comment: That is a very reasonable answer - thanks for sharing your knowledge with me!! hehehe, whenever i see the term *Stack* in an algorithm, that leads me to using `Stack` but very right: `Deque` should be the tool of my choice!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

both return boolean only difference is isEmpty is synchronized points to vector whereas empty is not synchronized points to stack